# Перебор значений матрицы по диагонали, начиная от введенной координаты

Tags: python, матрицы, шахматы

Пишу программу для отображения возможных ходов слона на шахматной доске.

```
while True:
    v1 = input('Enter vertical position (A-H): ')
    if ord(v1) in range(ord('a'), ord('h') + 1):
        break

while True:
    h1 = int(input('Enter horizontal position (1-8): '))
    if h1 in range(1, 9):
        break
for i in range(ord('a'), ord('h') + 1):
    for j in range(1, 9):
        if( ( abs( i - ord(v1) ) == abs( j - h1 ) ) and ( i != ord(v1) or j != h1 ) ):
            if ( i != ord(v2) and j != h2 ):
                move = chr(i) + str(j)
                moves.append(move)
```

Необходимо обработать возможность "столкновения" с дружественной фигурой. Для этого цикл нужно начинать с координат вводимой фигуры и идти от них в 4 стороны. Не понимаю, как это сделать.

Comment: Стандартная задачка по программированию, ух помню в свое время я тоже не понимал, но начала и сделал, пришлось поломать голову конечно...

Comment: @RifmaMan, а не подскажете верное направление?